# Selected enum in comboBox to string?

Tags: c#

I'm using a comboBox with an enum of Countries, and I wonder how I get the selected country from the comboBox to a string. Previously I have used cmbCountries.SelectedIndex to get the int number of the selected country, but now I want the text. Help is preciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your combo box is data bound, then just use the index directly against the data.

If not, you can get the item from the control:

`cmbCountries.SelectedItem`

But if you want just the text value of the selected entry:

`cmbCountries.Text`

Answer (score 1):

rIf you enum has the same values as the combobox, just cast your selected index to a variable of your enum type and then do a `ToString()` on that.  a bit like this:

```
void Main()
{
    int selectedIndex = 1;
    Country test;
    test = (Country)selectedIndex;
    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(((Country)selectedIndex).ToString());
}

enum Country
{
    None,
    Australia,
    Austria,
    England,
    France,
    Germany,
    UnitedStates
}
```

Alternatively, you can just get the `Text` of the combobox.